# Click on element inside iFrame - Cypress

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cypress

Can anyone, please assist in following:

Want to click element which resides on found iframe. Also, imported plugin **import 'cypress-iframe';** in **commands** class.
Code for founding iframe and clicking on element:

```
clickIFrameElement(elementCss, element1Css) {
    cy.frameLoaded(elementCss);
    cy.iframe(elementCss).find(element1Css).then(function(){
       cy.get(element1Css).click({ force: true })
    })
}
```

In test, I call this command:

```
cy.frameLoaded(elementCss).eq(0);
cy.iframe().find(element1Css).should('be.visible').click()
```

It does find iframe, but do not click on element. Error which get:

```
Timed out retrying after 20000ms: Expected to find element: #grouped-pageload-Banner button[class*="save-consents evSpAcceptBtn"], but never found it.
```

HTML for iframe:
[image]

What I am doing wrong, or what is incorrect in code?

Thank you in advance

UPDATE

Tried also second approach with following command:

```
cy.iframe().find(#grouped-pageload-Banner button[class*="save-consents evSpAcceptBtn"]).should('be.visible').click()
```

But got second error:

```
cypress-iframe commands can only be applied to exactly one iframe at a time.  Instead found 7
```

Comment: You can use it in simple way like `cy.iframe('iframeID').find(LocatorsUnderIframe).type(data)`

Comment: @ Krupal Vaghasiya Tried this: cy.iframe('iFrameId).find(elementCss).click(), got uncaught:error

Comment: @ Krupal Vaghasiya Update my question with second approach, with another error. Did not got solution

Comment: Just confirmation, have you installed cypress-iframe plugin? Your iframe id should be `#ifrmCookieBanner` so your code should be `cy.iframe(#ifrmCookieBanner).find(#grouped-pageload-Banner button[class*="save-consents evSpAcceptBtn"]).should('be.visible').click()`

Comment: @Krupal Vaghasiya
Installed is cypress0iframe plugin anad added into commands.js as import 'cypress-iframe';

Regarding code, yes, exactly, that is how it looks

And throws error.

Comment: could you please show me error?

Comment: According to your error which you have posted in your question, is saying that there are multiple `iframe` with the same selector

Comment: @Krupal Vaghasiya Sorry for late response. If can be any help, here is public link: https://www.qover.com/

Comment: Okay, I am busy with other work. once I will get time, I will check and let you know

Comment: Please use this line in your script `cy.iframe('#ifrmCookieBanner').find('#grouped-pageload-Banner button[class*="save-consents evSpAcceptBtn"]').should('be.visible').click()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244801/discussion-between-zoran-and-krupal-vaghasiya).

Comment: @Krupal Vaghasiya
Uncaught exception solved issue, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please replace this line into your code

```
cy.iframe('#ifrmCookieBanner')
    .find('#grouped-pageload-Banner button[class*="save-consents evSpAcceptBtn"]')
    .should('be.visible')
    .click()
```

And put this in your `support/index.js`

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    // returning false here prevents Cypress from
    // failing the test
return false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the iframe URL belongs to the same domain of current window, otherwise, this cannot be executed for security reasons. But if you have how to install a Chrome extension in user, this action can be performed via content_script ;)

Comment: It is on same domain. Just neeed to either accept or decline cookies (which is inside of the one of seven different iframes on page). Not sure that understood following: "But if you have how to install a Chrome extension in user,.."

Comment: Updated question with second command, but without success